# Need simple terminal device for vpn access

Tags: vpn, terminal

I'm looking for a "simple terminal" device that we can use to access the VPN at a client site.  Contractors don't get laptops and this client does not allow personal computers to access their network either internally or via VPN.  Installing the vpn client software at home is forbidden.

In the office we use NComputing L230 Access Terminals so we can move around to conference rooms and connect to our desktop screens.  Unfortunately, NComputing doesn't have anything that will work via VPN.

I'd like to find something similar to the NComputing access terminal that we could use over VPN.  It would have to be something that people could not install software on, and more importantly would not be subject to viruses.

Does anyone know of a simple terminal solution for VPN access?

**Update:**

I guess I wasn't clear.

I'm looking for a VPN client that is immune to viruses, and that users cannot add any software to, and that will not allow any other device on the vpn.

Something like the NComputing L230 that has a VPN client is what I'm looking for.

Comment: immune to viruses? No such thing. That's like having a car that's immune to crashing. If it's running an OS then it can be infected. I see your point though - those NComputing devices are very simple. What is the technology on the other end of the device? Linux? Windows? RDP? VNC?

Comment: The technology on the other side of the NComputing L230 is a desktop PC.  The L230 is immune to viruses as far as I know.  You can't install anything on it.  I'm not sure how much of an OS the L230s run.  They may be Microsoft's equivalent of a dumb terminal.

Answer (score 1):

Digi makes some very small VPN routers that could compliment your L230 that also work over cellular 3G networks.  It would solve your issue of accessing the LAN as well as getting on the VPN.

http://www.digi.com/products/cellulargateways/digiconnectwanfamily.jsp

Comment: I don't see how a router solves the problem of a vpn client that is locked down.

Comment: By using your own router + cellular modem you're creating your own connection to the Internet that is completely independent of your client.  You will not touch their network and the Digi routers have built in VPN so you can connect to your VPN via the Internet and still connect with your terminal.

Answer (score 1):

You could put Linux onto a Linksys WRT54GL, install the VPN software onto that, then stick any old device behind it.

We've done this for some of our clients that wanted something quick and easy :)

Comment: The "stick any old device behind it" is a deal killer.  They absolutely won't allow anything but their own devices on their network.

Comment: In that case, configure the Linksys to only accept traffic from a specific device (perhaps by MAC). However, since a MAC is easily spoofable, this isn't as secure a solution as an all-in-one device.

Answer (score 1):

The hardware version of the [Sun Ray](http://www.oracle.com/us/technologies/virtualization/sun-ray/overview/index.html) (if they still make it) could be what you're looking for.  You'll need some services on your side to support it, but there's not much at all running on the client side.  I worked at a .gov that rolled them out with huge success.  That was before the Oracle buyout, so I don't know what they look like these days.

The Sun Ray can VPN back (to a Cisco VPN, possibly others) to get the initial desktop if you've configured it.  We didn't have trouble with people using them at home over middle-of-the-road DSL connections.

Comment: Geez, old question is old.  Sorry about the bump!  I hope this is still useful to someone.